# How to autotype in a desired form input on keyboard press?

Tags: javascript, html, auto, onkeypress

I want the function "automove" to take whatever is typed on the keyboard and move to the desired input and autotype in it. The "autotab" function tabs between the various input fields.

When I type on the keyboard it should move to the desired input(letter1) field and start typing there.

```
function automove(){
    letter1.focus()

}

function autotab(current,to){
    if (current.getAttribute && 
        current.value.length==current.getAttribute("maxlength")) {
        to.focus() 
        }
}
```